# How do I create and insert one-to-many object with entity framework c#

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, one-to-many

I'm trying to create an object and insert to the database but keep getting the same error no matter what I try. 
The row that I get the error on is ColumnGroupTest.ValidValues.Add(memberComment1); the error is

**error message**

> NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

**my models**

```
    public class StoreColumnName
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StoreColumnGroupName { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public string ColumnType { get; set; }
        public List<StoreValidValue> ValidValues { get; set; }
    }

    public class StoreValidValue
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ValidValue { get; set; }
        public StoreColumnName StoreColumnName { get; set; }
    }
```

**my controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Physical.xml");
        var result = document.Descendants("ColumnGroup");
        foreach(var item in result){    
                var ColumnGroupName = item.Attribute("name").Value;
                var Columns = item.Descendants("Column");

                foreach (var itemColumn in Columns)
                {
                    StoreColumnName ColumnGroup = new StoreColumnName();
                    var ColumnGroupTest = new StoreColumnName
                    {
                        StoreColumnGroupName = ColumnGroupName, 
                        ColumnName = itemColumn.Attribute("name").Value, 
                        ColumnType = itemColumn.Attribute("type").Value, 
                        Id = 11
                    };
                    var ValidValues = itemColumn.Descendants("ValidValues");
                    var Values = ValidValues.Descendants("Value");

                    foreach (var Value in Values)
                    {
                        var memberComment1 = new StoreValidValue
                        {
                            StoreColumnName = ColumnGroupTest,
                            ValidValue = Value.Value,
                            Id = 101
                        };
                        ColumnGroupTest.ValidValues.Add(memberComment1);
                    }
                }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

(I gladly take tips on what I can improve when asking for help/guiding here).

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please add details about the exception like the stack trace and any inner exceptions, if available. Usually, NullReferenceException does not have an inner exception. But looking at the exception information will solve half your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you're having is that you don't initialize your `ValidValues` property to a list. By default, those types of properties initialize to `null` unless you specify differently.

The best approach is to add that initialization to your constructor of that object.

```
public StoreColumnName() {
    this.ValidValues = new List<StoreValidValue>();
}
```